# How to `chartr` a "-" (or escaping ranges)?

Tags: r, string, replace

In R one can use `chartr` to change characters from one to another, eg.:

```
chartr("aor","u ^","Stackoverflow")
[1] "Stuck ve^fl w"
```

Pattern could be ranges (e.g. `chartr("a-hwo","0-9","Stackoverflow")`), but length need to match.

But how to replace `"-"`?

```
> chartr("ab-;","1234","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
Error in chartr("ab-;", "1234", "aaa bbb ccc --- ;") : 
  decreasing range specification ('b-;')

> chartr(";-ab","4312","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
Error in chartr(";-ab", "4312", "aaa bbb ccc --- ;") : 
  'old' is longer than 'new'

> chartr("ab\-;","1234","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
Error: '\-' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""ab\-"

> chartr("ab--;","1234","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
Error in chartr("ab--;", "1234", "aaa bbb ccc --- ;") : 
  decreasing range specification ('b--')
```

I found one workaround - putting char at the beginning or the end:

```
> chartr("ab;-","1243","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
[1] "111 222 ccc 333 4"
```

But I using this to randomly replace chars so in my pattern `"-"` could be anywhere:

```
chartr(
    old = "-!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ "
    ,new = "-!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ " %>% strsplit("") %>% .[[1]] %>% sample %>% paste(collapse="")
    , x = "x@&*#--s"
) # this randomly is ok or throw error (about length or decreasing range)
```

Is there way to turn off ranges / escape range character / etc?

Comment: Not that I know of, but if you're willing to use `stringi::stri_trans_char("aaa bbb ccc --- ;", "ab-;","1234")`, then it works.

Comment: @Jota This is a very decent alternative.

Answer (score 3):

The unicode code point for `-`  is lower than a, thus the error stating

> decreasing range specification ('b--')

So you need to place it before `a` if using a range

without a range:

```
chartr("-;ab","1234","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
# [1] "333 444 ccc 111 2"
```

You can subsequently use `-` to denote a range (keeping the lengths matching in old and new

```
`chartr("-a-c;","12b34","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
# [1] "222 bbb 333 111 4"
```

Comment: Ok, but you're referring one of problems. I don't want ranges at all. As you write lengths need to match. I understand error messages :).

Answer (score 0):

If you force every value to be a range extending from itself to itself, you can do:

```
old <- ";-ab"
new <- "4312"

splcomb <- function(x) gsub("(.)", "\\1-\\1", x)

splcomb(old)
#[1] ";-;---a-ab-b"

chartr(splcomb(old), splcomb(new), "aaa bbb ccc --- ;")
#[1] "111 222 ccc 333 4"
```

Comment: Nice one. It seems that the only one needed is that before dash: `chartr("ab-b-;","1234","aaa bbb ccc --- ;")`