# How to transform an email address name? Ex, 'ab_1@email.com' to 'VCSN@email.com' (vowel-consonant-symbol-number))

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, slice

I'm trying to analyze email addresses name (anything before the @ symbol)in r for pattern detection. I want transform each element to a representation. For example, 'ty_00@mail.com' would be 'CCSNN' (consonant-consonant-symbol-number-number). I'm trying to use an ifelse() statement but it isn't working. Maybe a function would work better? But my coding skills are somewhat limited.

```
n =c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
v=c('a','e','i','o','u')
c=c('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')
s=c("!","#","$","%","&","'","*","+","-","/","=","?","^","_","`","{")



string1= 'jack0_d'
data$string1 <- ifelse(data$string1 %in% n, "N","?" |
                       data$string1 %in% v, "V","?" |
                       data$string1 %in% c, "C","?" |
                       data$string1 %in% s, "S","?" )

'Error in ifelse(data$string1 %in% n, "N", "?" | data$string1 %in% v, "V",  : 
  unused arguments ("V", "?" | data$string1 %in% c, "C", "?" | data$string1 %in% s, "S", "?")'
```

'jack0_d' would be CVCCNSC

Answer (score 3):

`chartr` takes two character strings of the same length and translates each character of the third argument found in the first string to the corresponding character in the second.  The minus sign signifies a range of characters to `chartr` unless at the end so we put it there. No packages or regular expressions are used.

```
input <- c('ab_1', 'ty_00', 'jack0_d')

L <- list(N = n, V = v, C = c, S = c(setdiff(s, "-"), "-"))
transl <- sapply(stack(L), paste, collapse = "")
chartr(transl[1], transl[2], input)
## [1] "VCSN"    "CCSNN"   "CVCCNSC"
```

### Update

fixed.

Comment: I think if you put the `-` at the very end of the `old=` argument to `chartr()` it should be replaced literally rather than as a range.

Comment: I tried it at the beginning and at the end but got errors.

Comment: `x <- "blah-de-blah"; chartr("a-z-","A-Z!",x)` seems to work. Ah.. I see you're right though - it still is taken as a range if there is something after the value. Previous discussion here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013203/how-to-chartr-a-or-escaping-ranges

Comment: I must have had some other error the first time.  I have put it at the end now and it does seem to work.  Have used that to slightly simplify answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `%in%` function only works to check if something is an element of a vector. To check within individual strings, you can use regular expressions. One way is to use `stringr` like this. We collapse the vectors with the `|` separator to indicate "or", and then replace with the desired letter. Note that I added `\\` in front of the symbols in `s`, since some symbols are special characters in regular expressions but we just want to match them literally. (not all needed to be escaped but I just did them all for simplicity)

```r
library(stringr)
n <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0")
v <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
c <- c("b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
s <- c("\\!", "\\#", "\\$", "\\%", "\\&", "\\'", "\\*", "\\+", "\\-", "\\/", "\\=", "\\?", "\\^", "\\_", "\\`", "\\{")

strings <- c("jack0_d", "ab_1")

strings %>%
  str_replace_all(str_c(n, collapse = "|"), "N") %>% 
  str_replace_all(str_c(v, collapse = "|"), "V") %>% 
  str_replace_all(str_c(c, collapse = "|"), "C") %>%
  str_replace_all(str_c(s, collapse = "|"), "S")
#> [1] "CVCCNSC" "VCSN"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>